# iterar valores em $.each aninhado Jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou recebendo uma tabela completa do meu server side, procuro por `td` com uma informação que quero e salvo essa `tr` inteira em uma variável como abaixo:

```
var rowVoo;

$(table).find("tr td").each(function () {
      if ($.trim($(this).text()) == "Porto Velho - RO") {
           rowVoo = $(this).closest("tr");
      }
});
```

A variável `rowVoo` fica como fica como abaixo:

```
<tr>
    <td>Porto Velho - RO</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>1 ( 9.1 %)</td>
    <td>0 ( 0 %)</td>
    <td>0 ( 0 %)</td>
</tr>
```

Tenho uma lista como abixo:

```
<ul class="list-voos">
      <li><span></span> VOOS PREVISTOS</li>
      <li><span></span> ATRASADOS AGORA</li>
      <li><span></span> VOOS CANCELADOS</li>
      <li><span></span> ATRASADOS NO DIA</li>
</ul>
```

Preciso passar os valores que estão dentro dos `td` para os `span` que estão dentro da lista.

Procuro pelos `span` que estão dentro da list:

```
var list = $(".list-voos").find("li").find("span");
```

E tento iterar os valores:

```
$(rowVoo).find("td").each(function () {
     var that = $(this);
     $(list).each(function () {
         console.log($(this).text(that.text()));
         return null;
     });
});
```

Porém os valores são duplicados e os `span` da list sempre ficam com o último valor da `td`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tens de usar o `index` que a função [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) passa/disponibiliza.

Testa assim:

```
var lis = $('ul.list-voos li');
$(rowVoo).find("td").each(function (i) {
     $(lis).find('span').eq(i).html(this.innerHTML);
});
```

> **function** (index, value){

O método each permite uma função que te dá duas variáveis. A primeira é o indice do elemento na coleção, o segundo é o proprio elemento da coleção. No caso do jQuery, é o mesmo valor do `this` dentro dessa função.

**Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/CrXD4/2/**

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 2):

maior desempenho[atualizado]:

```
var i, e, tableTeste = $("table").find("tr td"),
  ulLi = $(".list-voos").find("li span");

for (var i = 0, e = tableTeste.length; i < e; i++) {
  var tdValue = tableTeste[i].innerHTML;

  ulLi.eq(i).html(tdValue);


}
```

antes:

```
var i, e, tableTeste = $("table").find("tr td"),
  ulLi = $(".list-voos").find("li span");

for (var i = 0, e = tableTeste.length; i < e; i++) {
  var tdValue = tableTeste.eq(i).html();
  ulLi.eq(i).html(tdValue);

}
```

veja a comparação usando each(), for(){} e for(){} com innerHTML: http://jsperf.com/test-each-for-each/2